# Validate a Functor's Target Object

Tags: c++, functor, pointer-to-member

I have class `foo` that accepts a member function pointer to one of class `bar`'s methods, but class bar may have shorter lifetime than `foo` is there a way that the Functor can check for `bar`s existence before executing?

Currently, I'm trying to use `std::function`'s `bool operator` without success.

```
class Foo
{
public:
    void Foo::SetCallback( std::function< void( void ) > cb )
    {
        _cb = cb; // My Bar class will call this to assign a Bar member function pointer to Foo's _cb member variable
    }
    void Foo::CallCallback()
    {
        if( _cb ) _cb(); // This evaluates to true even if the original bar object has been destroyed
        //I want this callback to only execute if the bar object exists
    }
private:
    std::function< void( void ) > _cb;
};
class Bar
{
public:
    Bar( Foo* _foo )
    {
        _foo->SetCallback( std::bind( &myCalledbackFunc, this );
    }
    void myCalledbackFunc()
    {
        //do stuff
    }
};
```

Comment: Sorry your question is completely unclear to me. What is `bar` exactly? Please put a [minimal sample](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reproduces the behavior and errors you actually get.

Comment: What about having a weak_ptr of the bar instance in addition to the functor as function parameters?

Comment: @SilvesterSeredi sounds like a good idea... I'm not familiar with `std::weak_ptr` though could I simply create one from `this` in my `Bar` ctor?

Comment: You can have `register_callback`, and `deregister_callback` functions in foo and deregister the callback in the destructor of the `bar` class.

Comment: @perreal that is the temporary solution that I have in place... I was just hoping that the Functor could be used to identify the existence of the class it referenced a member of.

Comment: @perreal I'm sad to say that I think this temporary solution is the best thing that is available to us in C++11. If you type this up as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C++ the memory used by an object is not zeroed on destruction of the object. So as [Silvester Seredi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2459583/silvester-seredi) mentions in his answer the only way for any pointer to know whether the object that it references has been destroyed is for the pointer to reference an object owning auto-pointer. It is additionally notable that an object cannot be owned internally, so an object cannot intrinsically provide an indicator to whether it has been destroyed.

Therefore, the only solution is to notify the class holding the functor that it is invalid upon the destruction of the class the functor references a member of, as is suggested by [perreal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/390913/perreal). Note that this is not multi-thread safe.

```
class Foo
{
public:
    void SetCallback( std::function< void( void ) > cb )
    {
        _cb = cb;
    }
    void UnSetCallback()
    {
        _cb = std::function< void( void ) >();
    }
    void CallCallback()
    {
        if( _cb ) _cb();
    }
private:
    std::function< void( void ) > _cb;
};
class Bar
{
public:
    Bar( Foo* foo ) : _foo( foo )
    {
        _foo->SetCallback( std::bind( &myCalledbackFunc, this );
    }
    ~Bar()
    {
        _foo->UnSetCallback();
    }
    void myCalledbackFunc()
    {
        //do stuff
    }
private:
    Foo _foo;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't think of any simple way how to let Foo know when the callback object is destroyed, but if you really want to verify from the Foo class whether the object is alive, I'd use a weak_ptr somewhere along the road. If you are creating Bar through `new` you could instead create the instances through `make_shared` and you'd do something like this (the additional cost is one function call after every construction of a Bar instance):

```
class Bar;
class Foo
{
public:
    void Foo::SetCallback( std::function< void( void ) > cb )
    {
        _cb = cb;
    }

    void Foo::RegisterBar(std::weak_ptr<Bar> inbarPtr)
    {
        barRef = inbarPtr;
    }

    void Foo::CallCallback()
    {
        if( _cb && !barRef.expired()) _cb(); 
    }

private:
    std::function< void( void ) > _cb;
    std::weak_ptr<Bar> barRef;
};

class Bar
{
public:
    Bar( Foo* _foo )
    {
        _foo->SetCallback( std::bind( &Bar::myCalledbackFunc, this ));
    }
    void myCalledbackFunc()
    {
        //do stuff
    }
};

int main()
{
    Foo fooInstace;
    std::shared_ptr<Bar> barInstance = std::make_shared<Bar>(&fooInstace);
    fooInstace.RegisterBar(barInstance);
    return 0;
}
```

If you really insist on changes only to the Bar class, you could use this ugly, ugly hack with an empty custom deleter:

```
class Bar;
class Foo
{
public:
  void Foo::SetCallback( std::function< void( void ) > cb , std::weak_ptr<Bar> inbarPtr)
  {
    _cb = cb;
    barRef = inbarPtr;
  }
  void Foo::CallCallback()
  {
    if( _cb && !barRef.expired()) _cb(); 
  }
private:
  std::function< void( void ) > _cb;
  std::weak_ptr<Bar> barRef;
};


class Bar
{
  std::shared_ptr<Bar> selfPtr;
public:
  Bar( Foo* _foo )
  {
    selfPtr = std::shared_ptr<Bar>(this, Bar::EmptyDeleter);
    _foo->SetCallback( std::bind( &Bar::myCalledbackFunc, this ), selfPtr);
  }
  void myCalledbackFunc()
  {
    //do stuff
  }
protected:
  static void EmptyDeleter(Bar*)
  {
  }
};
```

Comment: So in my code, my `Bar` example class is created by a template factory, and the factory hangs onto it with a `std::unique_ptr` and will be responsible for cleaning it up. I can't change the factory code because of what that would mean for the rest of the design. Is there a way I could pull your solution off using only the code *inside* the `Bar` class?

Comment: Can't you just change the unique_ptr to a shared_ptr? The change should be trivial

Comment: Looking at the code that looks like a pretty major change... Let's say I can make it though... I still can't get at the `std::shared_ptr` that the factory holds to my `Bar` object from within the `Bar` class. So I don't think switching actually buys me anything.

Comment: What about the solution with the empty custom deleter (the second solution in my answer)?

Comment: Man... I need to understand this better... Is this saying that `selfPtr` would never get cleaned up? @perreal's comment currently seems preffered to this.

Comment: Exactly. This leaves the deletion of the Bar instance to the owning factory unique_ptr. Otherwise the destructor of selftPtr would delete the pointer it owns, i.e. the pointer to this. But this would cause a double delete since the destructor of selftPtr is called only in the destructor of Bar.